# How to change the number of auto suggested record limit of Many2One field?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

There is a field `product_id` in `sale.order.line` model that is a Many2One field. There are a ton of product data inside the database. Right now, when a user fills in some characters, it will suggest some records filtered by the given characters. However, it is limited to only 7 records with a search more option underneath it.

My question is how to customize it so that it will return any number of records? (I will fine-tune later to come up with the number of satisfied limit)

I have tried messing with Autocomplete widget and FieldMany2One in the javascript files, but to no avail.

Comment: You can use a ready solution, but it comes with more than only this requirement: [web_m2x_options by OCA](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/14.0/web_m2x_options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limit` is hard coded in [init](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/relational_fields.js#L121) function

You can alter the `FieldMany2One` widget and make it possible to set the limit  in the field options

***Example:***

```js
var relationalFields = require('web.relational_fields');

relationalFields.FieldMany2One.include({
    init: function (parent, name, record, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.limit = this.nodeOptions.limit || this.limit;

    },
});
```

To set the limit to `10`, just set the limit like following:

```
options="{'limit': 10}"
```